# Fining the best fit

Tags: python, list

***Hello people,***

I got a problem i can't figure out how to solve:

I have a ***selection of metal tubes*** available in storage and i need to cut them to ***get
shorter sections*** to build some frames.

I need to write a script that can tell me from which tubes out of those available i should get the different sections to have the least waste possible.

*I basically have two lists of numbers and I need to find how to best fit the numbers of the first list in the numbers of the second list.*

I need to make it in python but I don't necessarily need the actual code. I just can't find the logical approach I should follow.

Does anyone have any idea?

*Thanks!*

P.s. i'm veeeery new ro stack-overflow i hope i'm doing everything right. Please have patience with me ;)

Comment: some reproducible example could help

Comment: The easiest approach would be brute force

Comment: Are you familiar with [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)?

Comment: No not really, should i look into it to solve the issue?